# Handling several different form input fields php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, forms

My site contains several forms for users to fill. One of those forms could result in a lot of work. That´s why I´m reaching out for consent. You see, in this form, there will be 40 games. And every game gives the users 2 fields to enter a number (depending on how they think the game will end). So with 40-50 games it means that I have 80-90 fields to keep track of. The two fields will be paired with the right game in the database, and the users answer will be remembered at all time. This is a snap of my code:

```
<div class="form-left">England- Italy</div>
                <div class="form-right"><input type="result" id="g1r1" name="g1r1" class="form-input" /></div>
                <div class="form-dash">-</div>
                <div class="form-right"><input type="result" id="g1r2" name="g1r2" class="form-input" /></div>
                <div class="form-error"></div>

<div class="form-left">Spain- Mexico</div>
                <div class="form-right"><input type="result" id="g2r1" name="g2r1" class="form-input" /></div>
                <div class="form-dash">-</div>
                <div class="form-right"><input type="result" id="g2r2" name="g2r2" class="form-input" /></div>
                <div class="form-error"></div>
```

My thought is, naming the games game1row1 and game1row2. To be able to match them to the correct game in the database. Problem is that an insertion to a table with 90 fields seems hugh. So my question would be: *How can this be done in a better way? With less lines of code on the insert-database side..*

```
  insert into tablename ( g1r1, g1r2 values 1, 0 where MATCH_ID = MATCHID)
```

**EDIT**

To clarify, My table contains ID, user_id, match_id(g), homeScore(r1), awayScore(r2).
My idea of g1r1 and g1r2 is to save r1 and r2 at right g(game).

Comment: You can dynamically make the insert query. I don't know how else you would do it. What do you have so far?

Comment: I don't have much more than making 40 insert querys, but I was thinking something in line with an array to store matchers och rows, but then again I have no idea, thats why im asking. What do you mean by dynamically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**`Problem is that an insertion to a table with 90 fields seems hug[e]`**

your user table should be seperate from your games table and a third table for scores I think is how you are using this. That way none of the tables will ever have 90 columns. This will also allow a design that allows database growth

What I think your current design is:

```
usser_id | g1r1 | g1r2 | g2r1 | g2r2 | g3r1 | g3r2 | ... | g50r1 | g50r2
```

What your design should be like

```
Users:
user_id | ..[user info]...

Games:
game_id | ...[game info]...

Scores:
score_id | game_id | user_id | score_1 | score_2
```

And by all means also follow @bart2puck with his recommendation of writing html dynamically with php. This will make life so much easier. After changing database design, you will be able to insert the scores like:

```
$insert = "INSERT INTO Scores (user_id,game_id,homeScore,awayScore) VALUES ";
foreach ($_POST['games'] as $key => $value){
    $insert = "(".$_POST["user_id"].",".$key.",".$value[0].",".$value[1].")";
}
//run query insert
```

That is if you name your input fields according to `name="games[game_id[]]"` where `game_id` is equivalent to your database `game_id` for instance for game 1 : `name="game[1[]]"` for both of the score fields for that game.

**IMPORTANT!!**

Please make sure that you either use query parameters or mysql escape your post input before running query! That way you will be protected from [Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) AKA SQL Injection

**EDIT:**

From the OP comment with table names you may want to use

```
$insert = "INSERT INTO Scores (user_id, game_id, homeScore, awayScore) VALUES ";
foreach ($_POST["homeScore"] as $key => $value){
    $insert = "(".$_POST["user_id"].",".$key.",".$value.",".$_POST["awayScore"][$key].")";
}
//run query insert
```

Where you then name your form fileds `homeScore[game_id]` and `awayScore[game_id]` so the home score field of the game with a game id of 1 would be `name="homeScore[1]"`

**EDIT 2:**

Here is also a better way to write your html using php with the correct form names if you follow my last edit.

```
for ($i = 1;$i<=40;$i++){
   echo "<div class='form-right'><input type='result' id='homeScore[$i]' name='awayScore[$i]' class='form-input' /></div>\n";
   }
}
```

Comment: I accually have a Scores table -> id, user_id, game_id, homeScore, awayScore. But the insertion part looks promising, just gonna try it and then I leave my verdict, thanks :)

Comment: @Rocksteady Ok from your question and 90 fields, I thought you had a table with 90 columns.. anyways I hope that it helps. and remember to watch out for [Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/)

Comment: @Rocksteady please see my edited answer, As I believe it will help.

Comment: user id wont be posted, I can always get that, but the most importand is that G1 gets placed at match_id and r1 and r2 is matched to right match_id. Im setting up a test for you code right now

Comment: You have found a good way here, the problem now is that ".$_POST["awayScore"][$key]." does not display the user input, it displays the match_id...

Answer (score 1):

1)  you could write your page using a loop and make the form names an array

```
 echo "<form action='$PHP_SELF' method='POST'>";
 for ($b = 1;$b<=40;$b++)
 {
   $gameId = "g" . $b;
   for ($a = 1;$a<=2;$a++)
   {
     $roundId = "r" . $a;
     $fieldName = $gameId . $roundId;

      echo "<div class='form-right'><input type='result' id='games[$fieldName]' name='games[$fieldName]' class='form-input' /></div>\n";
   }
}
 echo "<input type='submit' value='submit'>";
```

the post result would give you something like:

```
[games] => Array
    (
        [g1r1] => a
        [g1r2] => b
        [g2r1] => c
        [g2r2] => d
        [g3r1] => e
        [g3r2] => f
        [g4r1] => g
        [g4r2] => h
        [g5r1] => i
        [g5r2] => j
        [g6r1] => k
        [g6r2] => l
        [g7r1] => m
        [g7r2] => n
        [g8r1] => o
        [g8r2] => p
        [g9r1] => q
        [g9r2] => r
        [g10r1] => s
        [g10r2] => t
    )
```

and in your processing page:

```
 foreach ($_POST['games'] as $key => $value)
 {
    $insert = "INSERT into games (" . $key . ") values ('" . $value. "')";
   //or whatever query you need here.
 }
```

Comment: @Piero This way he can write 80 lines of a form in 10 lines with the php loop.

Answer (score 1):

bart2puck, what's the reason of outputting html with a php loop? Regular html would work just fine there, helping save bits of server resources. Form fields just should be named appropriately like so:

```
<input type="text" name="games[g1r1]" value="g1r1" />
```

Then in php get not just `$_POST` but `$_POST['games']` and you have the array of all form fields.

Then you could create your query like so:

```
$query = 'INSERT INTO `tablename`(`'.implode('`, `', array_keys($_POST['games'])).'`) VALUES("'.implode('", "', $_POST['games']).'")';
```

Just one liner.

Remember to clean all your data before saving to database or your application might be vulnerable to SQL injections.